# Revtex 4.1: Spacing in citation and superscript-affiliation IDs

Tags: spacing, revtex, affiliation, multiple-citations

I have a question (kind of obsession) about the "after comma" spacing when drafting a revtex 4.1 document.

1. When citing many references using the in-line square-bracket format, there is an unwanted space after the comma that separate two neighboring keys. (I can use something like

   ```
   \setcitestyle{numbers,square,citesep={,\kern-.24em}}
   ```

to remove it, but it seems quite artificial...)

2. This space also appears when multiple affiliations occur (in my example: between two affiliation IDs for Second Author, and between the affiliation ID and the * for First Author).

Could anyone help me to solve this annoying question? Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,eqsecnum,aps,pra,superscriptaddress,10pt,]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\setcitestyle{numbers,square,citesep={,\kern-.24em}}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{First Author}\email{first.author@domain.name}\affiliation{Affiliation 1}
\author{Second Author}\affiliation{Affiliation 1}\affiliation{Affiliation 2}
\author{Third Author}\affiliation{Affiliation 1}
%\date{}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Here we cite two references \cite{Aaa16,Bbb16}.

\section{Conclusions}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname bibnamefont\endcsname\relax
  \def\bibnamefont#1{#1}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname bibfnamefont\endcsname\relax
  \def\bibfnamefont#1{#1}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname citenamefont\endcsname\relax
  \def\citenamefont#1{#1}\fi
\providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}

\bibitem[{\citenamefont{Aaa}(2016)}]{Aaa16}
\bibinfo{author}{\bibfnamefont{A.}~\bibnamefont{Aaa}}, \bibinfo{journal}{Journal A} \textbf{\bibinfo{volume}{1}}, \bibinfo{pages}{1} (\bibinfo{year}{2016}).

\bibitem[{\citenamefont{Bbb et~al.}(2016)\citenamefont{Bbb, Ccc, and Aaa}}]{Bbb16}
\bibinfo{author}{\bibfnamefont{B.} \bibnamefont{Bbb}}, \bibinfo{author}{\bibfnamefont{C.}~\bibnamefont{Ccc}}, \bibnamefont{and} \bibinfo{author}{\bibfnamefont{A.}~\bibnamefont{Aaa}}, \bibinfo{journal}{Journal B} \textbf{\bibinfo{volume}{1}}, \bibinfo{pages}{1} (\bibinfo{year}{2016}).
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don’t see the problem.  There should be a space after the comma.

Comment: But I don't see the space in either the APS document auguide4-1.pdf or the papers on, e.g., PRB. That's why I said "obsession". :)

Comment: I have the same problem regarding the multiple citations. It is annoying that this behavior is different from the one on the final published paper.